# Deriving the Normalization formula for Associated Legendre functions: Stage $2$ of $4$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, legendre-polynomials

The question that follows is a continuation of [this previous Stage $1$ question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756218/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-1) needed as part of a derivation of the **Associated Legendre Functions Normalization Formula:** $$\color{blue}{\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}[{P_{L}}^m(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\left(\frac{2}{2L+1}\right)\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}}$$ where for each $m$, the functions $${P_L}^m(x)=\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\tag{1}$$ are a set of Associated Legendre functions on $[−1, 1]$.

`The question in my textbook asks me to`

> Write $(1)$ with $m$ replaced with $-m$ then use the fact that [$$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L&=\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\left(x^2-1\right)^m\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\end{align}\quad \longleftarrow\text{(Stage 1)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756218/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-1) to show that $${P_L}^{-m}(x)=(-1)^m\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}{P_L}^{m}(x)\tag{2}$$

---

`Start of attempt:`

$$\begin{align}\require{enclose}{P_L}^{-m}(x)&=
\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\\&=
\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-m/2}\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\left(x^2-1\right)^m\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\quad\quad\longleftarrow\bbox[#AFA]{\text{Using Stage 1}}\\&=
\frac{(-1)^{-m/2}}{2^LL!}\left(x^2-1\right)^{-m/2}\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\left(x^2-1\right)^m\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\\&=
\frac{(-1)^{-m/2}}{2^LL!}\left(x^2-1\right)^{m/2}\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\\&=
\frac{\color{#F8F}{\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\color{black}{(-1)^{-m/2}}}}\cdot\color{#F8F}{\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\color{black}{(-1)^{m/2}}}}}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\\&=
\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\\&=
\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}{P_{L}}^m(x)\quad\quad\longleftarrow\bbox[#FFA]{\text{By substituting Equation (1)}}\\&\ne
(-1)^m\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}{P_L}^{m}(x)\end{align}$$
`End of attempt.`

---

So basically I am missing a factor of $(-1)^m$ as the $(-1)^{-m/2}$ and $(-1)^{m/2}$ cancelled each other out, and I'm therefore unable to prove Equation $(2)$. I have checked the proof for errors and am unable to find any. I am guessing that I have overlooked something simple thus making a trivial mistake somewhere along the line.

Is anyone able to locate and explain where I have made the error?

---

### EDIT:

Taking the advice of the answer given by Markus:

$$\begin{align}\require{enclose}{P_L}^{-m}(x)&=
\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\\&=
\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-m/2}\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\left(x^2-1\right)^m\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\quad\quad\longleftarrow\bbox[#FA8]{\text{Using Stage 1}}\\&=
\frac{1}{2^LL!}(-1)^m\left(1-x^2\right)^m\left(1-x^2\right)^{-m/2}\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\\&=
(-1)^m\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\\&=
(-1)^m\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}{P_{L}}^m(x)\quad\quad\longleftarrow\bbox[#AFF]{\text{By substituting Equation (1)}}\end{align}$$
as required ..... but only thanks to Markus :) ..... and not me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First note that your calculation is correct when $m$ is *even*. But when $m=$ is *odd* the expression
>   \begin{align*}
>   (-1)^{-\frac{m}{2}}
>   \end{align*}
>   has to be considered as value of the *multivalued* complex square root function.

In this case the rule valid for *real* $a,b\geq 0$, namely
\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}
  \end{align*}
does no longer hold.

See for instance *[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12)* which lies at the heart of the problem.

> But you could instead factor out $(-1)^m$ from
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \left(x^2-1\right)^m=(-1)^m(1-x^2)^m
>   \end{align*}
>   to obtain the wanted result.

Comment: @BLAZE: Sorry, I'm sometimes busy and can't always answer immediately. Your interpretation seems to be somewhat wrong. If we consider odd $m=2k+1$, we obtain $(1-x^2)^{-\frac{m}{2}}=(1-x^2)^{-k}\dot(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. The problematic factor is $(1-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\pm i(x^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and the multiplicity $\pm i$ can't be usefully avoided in the context of this example. So, we simply have to *avoid* this ambiguity.

Comment: @BLAZE:  A nice  discussion of this situation  can   be  found in chapter VI   of *[Visual Complex Analysis](http://umv.science.upjs.sk/hutnik/NeedhamVCA.pdf)*, especially the text with focus  figure [34].

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and helpful link. It's okay, I know you cannot answer immediately. Sometimes I take ages to answer, as I have to attend lectures and do lab-work, so I understand. Could you please take a look at [Stage 3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771821/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-3) and let me know if you agree that there is a typo in `Problem 9`? You can either make a comment or an answer (just a few short lines will do) and then I will upvote and accept it. Since currently no one is responding. Thank you :-)