# Deriving the Normalization formula for Associated Legendre functions: Stage $3$ of $4$

Tags: derivatives, legendre-polynomials

The question that follows is a continuation of [this Stage $1$ question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756218/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-1) and [this previous Stage $2$ question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770189/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-2) which are needed as part of a derivation of the **Associated Legendre Functions Normalization Formula:** $$\color{blue}{\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}[{P_{L}}^m(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\left(\frac{2}{2L+1}\right)\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}}$$ where for each $m$, the functions $${P_L}^m(x)=\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\tag{1}$$ are a set of Associated Legendre functions on $[−1, 1]$.

`The question in my textbook asks me to`

> Use [$$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L&=\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}\left(x^2-1\right)^m\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\end{align}\quad \longleftarrow\text{(Stage 1)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756218/show-that-dfrac-rmdl-m-rmdxl-m-leftx2-1-rightl-dfracl-m) to show that $${P_L}^{m}(x)=(-1)^m\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\tag{2}$$

---

`Start of attempt:`

I started with Stage $2$:
[$${P_L}^{-m}(x)=(-1)^m\frac{(L-m)!}{(L+m)!}{P_L}^{m}(x)\quad \longleftarrow\text{(Stage 2)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770189/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-2)
and rearranged it to get

$$\begin{align}\require{enclose}{P_L}^{m}(x)&=
\frac{1}{(-1)^m}\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}{P_L}^{-m}\\&=
(-1)^m\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\quad\longleftarrow\bbox[#F80]{\text{Using (1) with -m}}\end{align}$$
as required.

`End of attempt.`

---

So I have proved formula $(2)$; **but** I did *not* use the formula which it asked me to use.

So the question I have is: Did I *really* answer the question? Or is there some way it can be answered by using that formula?

For additional context please see the page below which is the source of questions from my textbook:

[image: Problems, Section 10]

If you have read the above extract and believe Problem $9$ cannot be done using Problem $7$ *alone* then please state this in a comment or an answer as there could be a typo in the book. Personally I think Problem $9$ should read "Use Problem $\color{#180}{8}$ to show that ....". If you agree with me please say something; I just need some kind of feedback.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of  all:

> - You have proven formula (9) and this is the most important aspect of this problem.
>
>   If it is stated as **hint** to use formula (7) you are free to use this formula or show the claim by other means which might look more convenient to you.
>
>   If it is phrased as **use formula (7) to show ...** - it is part of the exercise and to fully answer the exercise you should use the formula.

But, since you have proven formula (9) by means of (8) and you have also proven formula (8) by means of (7) you have mastered exercise (9) *in all its particulars*.

Please note, that *use formula (7)* does not imply *use formula (7) alone*. You are free to find your own derivation as long as formula (7) is an essential aspect in your proof.

> **Conclusio:** Having these aspects in mind and knowing that (7) implies (8) and vice versa (as we also know), both statements are equivalent and it is no longer *that important* if the author writes *use (7)* or *use (8)*.

Comment: @BLAZE: Thanks for accepting my answer. Good to see that it is helpful. Best regards,

Comment: Yes, it was all I needed to see, now proceeding to Stage $4/4$ (Problem 10 in the extract). Thanks.

Comment: @BLAZE:  Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll need it! It's pretty tough, so it will probably be posted as a question very soon :-)

Comment: Hi there; Can you please help me with the [F-i-n-a-l ~ S-t-a-g-e](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777484/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-4) of the derivation? I'm really stuck :(

Comment: Hi again, someone has given a very good answer to the [Stage 4 question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777484/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-4). The problem is; I just cannot understand the users answer. One of the reasons why I always call on you for help is because you have a very particular skill of explaining things in such a way that leaves me with effectively no choice but to understand your answers! I was wondering if you could work your magic again and explain in a comment or an answer to the Stage 4 question? Thank you.

Comment: BLAZE: This week I'm pretty busy. I will provide you with some info at the weekend if you won't have received all you need till then. Regards,

Comment: I know you're busy, but this is just to let you know I have placed a bounty on the [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777484/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-4), since no-one was able to explain it in simple terms :-)

Comment: @BLAZE: Thanks for the notification. I thought when reading the comment section of Stage 4/4 that everything is clear. I'll try to answer the question within the next 24 hours. Regards,