# Deriving the Normalization formula for Associated Legendre functions: Stage $4$ of $4$

Tags: integration, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials, integration-by-parts

The question that follows is the *final* stage of the previous $3$ stages found here: [Stage 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756218/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-1), [Stage 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770189/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-2?lq=1) and [Stage 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771821/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-3?lq=1) which are needed as part of a derivation of the **Associated Legendre Functions Normalization Formula:** $$\color{blue}{\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}[{P_{L}}^m(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\left(\frac{2}{2L+1}\right)\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}}\tag{1}$$ where for each $m$, the functions $${P_L}^m(x)=\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\tag{2}$$ are a set of Associated Legendre functions on $[−1, 1]$.

`The question in my textbook asks me to`

> Derive $(1)$ as follows: Multiply together the two formulas for ${P_{L}}^m(x)$ given by
>   $(2)$ and [$${P_L}^{m}(x)=(-1)^m\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}\frac{1}{2^LL!}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-m/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\quad\longleftarrow\text{(Stage 3)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771821/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-3) Then integrate by parts repeatedly lowering the $L+m$ derivative and raising the $L−m$ derivative until both are $L$ derivatives. Then use the ***regular* Normalization formula for Legendre Functions:** $$\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}[{P_{L}}(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2}{2L+1}\tag{3}$$ where ${P_{L}}(x)$ represents a Legendre function and ${P_{L}}^m(x)$ represents an *associated* Legendre function.

---

`Start of attempt:`

Multiplying together $(2)$ and the Stage $3$ formula yields:
$$[{P_{L}}^m(x)]^2=\frac{(-1)^m}{(2^LL!)^2}\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\tag{4}$$ Multiplying both sides of $(4)$ by $\mathrm{d}x$ and integrating gives:
$$\int[{P_{L}}^m(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{(-1)^m}{(2^LL!)^2}\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}\color{red}{\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,\mathrm{d}x}\tag{5}$$

Focusing now on the part marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ and integrating by parts:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m-1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m-1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\right|_{-1}^1-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m-1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m-1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m+1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=0-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m-1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m-1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m+1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\mathrm{d}x$$

`End of attempt.`

---

I don't know how to take this calculation any further as I have no idea how to evaluate
$$\color{#180}{\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m-1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m-1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m+1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\mathrm{d}x}$$

Could someone please help me reach equation $(1)$ and finally end this derivation of 
$$\color{blue}{\displaystyle\int_{x=-1}^{1}[{P_{L}}^m(x)]^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\left(\frac{2}{2L+1}\right)\frac{(L+m)!}{(L-m)!}}\tag{1}$$

---

### EDIT:

The Latex didn't render correctly in the description below the bounty; so I type it here instead:

One user has already given a detailed answer to this question that uses mathematical induction. The problem is that I am finding it hard to understand this type of proof as it is beyond my current level of understanding. I am looking for an answer that doesn't use mathematical induction. Could someone please explain in simple English (where possible) why

$\bbox[yellow]{\displaystyle-\int\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^{L+m-1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L+m-1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^{L-m+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{L-m+1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\mathrm{d}x}
$

$\bbox[yellow]{\displaystyle=(-1)^m\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}^L}{\mathrm{d}x^L}(x^2-1)^{L}\frac{\mathrm{d}^L}{\mathrm{d}x^L}(x^2-1)^L\mathrm{d}x}$

I desperately need to understand this as this forms the final part of a $4$ step proof.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I removed the bounty text because it didn't render properly. See the last part of the question body for the details of the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has more *explanatory character* since most of the calculcations we need were already done by OP or provided in the answer of @user5713492. For convenience only we introduce the operator notation
\begin{align*}
D_x:=\frac{d}{dx}
\end{align*}

> **First step:**
>   We  focus      at the *$\color{red}{red}$* part of OPs calculation and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \int&D_x^{L-m}\left(x^2-1\right)^LD_x^{L+m}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,dx\tag{1}\\
> &=\left.D_x^{L-m}\left(x^2-1\right)^LD_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\right|_{-1}^1\\
> &\qquad-\int D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
> &=0-\int D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
> &=-\int D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Comparing (1) with (2) we have successfully applied the *integration by parts* method and found
\begin{align*}
\int&D_x^{L-m}\left(x^2-1\right)^LD_x^{L+m}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,dx\\
&\qquad=-\int D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx
\end{align*}
We see the RHS has a minus sign in front and we have a change of the pair
\begin{align*}
(L-m,L+m)\quad\rightarrow\quad(L-m+1,L+m-1)\tag{3}
\end{align*}

We can read in the question of the textbook to apply *integration by parts* **iteratively**.  This means to successively apply the method to the already calculated results and so we do integration by parts with (2) again.

> **Second step:**
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> -\int&D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^LD_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,dx\\
> &=-\left.D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^LD_x^{L+m-2}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\right|_{-1}^1\\
> &\qquad+\int D_x^{L-m+2}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-2}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
> &=0+\int D_x^{L-m+2}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-2}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
> &=\int D_x^{L-m+2}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-2}\left(x^2-2\right)^Ldx\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   We see the RHS has  now a plus sign in front and we have a change of the pair
>   \begin{align*}
> (L-m+1,L+m-1)\quad\rightarrow\quad(L-m+2,L+m-2)
> \end{align*}

From this it is plausible how the iteration continues, namely 
\begin{align*}
\int&D_x^{L-m}\left(x^2-1\right)^LD_x^{L+m}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,dx\\
&=-\int D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
&=\int D_x^{L-m+2}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-2}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
&=-\int D_x^{L-m+3}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-3}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
&=\cdots\\
&=(-1)^{m-1}\int D_x^{L-m+(m-1)}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-(m-1)}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
&=(-1)^m\int D_x^{L-m+m}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-m}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
&\qquad=(-1)^m\int D_x^{L}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
\end{align*}

We observe, the sign in front of the integral alternates. It is obviously $(-1)^{\color{blue}{K}}$ corresponding with $D_x^{L-m+\color{blue}{K}}$. When we start with 
\begin{align*}
(L-m,L+m)\quad&\rightarrow\quad(L-m+1,L+m-1)\\
\end{align*}
we get after $m$ steps
\begin{align*}
(L-1,L+1)\quad&\rightarrow\quad(L,L)\\
\end{align*}

> **General step:**
>
> We are not content to argue based upon plausibility. We can rigorously show that everything claimed so far is valid. In fact this was done by the user @user5713492 right at the beginning of his answer (here with $K$ instead of $n$):
>
> The following is valid for $0\leq K <m$
>   \begin{align*}
> \int& D_x^{L-m+K}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-K}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
> &=-\int D_x^{L-m+K+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-K-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
> \end{align*}
>   The proof is precisely as we did it before in (2) and (4). Let $0\leq K <m$, then
>   \begin{align*}
> \int& D_x^{L-m+K}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-K}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\tag{5}\\
> &=\left.D_x^{L-m+K}\left(x^2-1\right)^LD_x^{L+m-K-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\right|_{-1}^1\\
> &\qquad-\int D_x^{L-m+K+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-K-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
> &=0-\int D_x^{L-m+K+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-K-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\\
> &=-\int D_x^{L-m+K+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-K-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}

This proof of the general step from (5) to (6) is all we need. Since it is valid for all $0\leq K<m$ we can use it with $K=0$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
\int& D_x^{L-m}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\qquad\quad&(K=0)\\
&=-\int D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^Ldx\qquad\quad&(K=1)\\
\end{align*}
then we *iteratively* set $K=0,1,\ldots,m-1$ to finally obtain after $m$ steps 
\begin{align*}
\int& D_x^{L-m}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,dx\qquad\quad&(K=0)\\
&=-\int D_x^{L-m+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+m-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,dx\qquad\quad&(K=1)\\
&=\cdots\\
&=(-1)^{m-1}\int D_x^{L-1}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L+1}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,dx\qquad\qquad&(K=m-1)\\
&=(-1)^m\int D_x^{L}\left(x^2-1\right)^{L}\,D_x^{L}\left(x^2-1\right)^L\,dx\\
\end{align*}
Since each step alternates the sign of the expression, we have after $m$ steps the sign $(-1)^m$. There are $m+1$ lines altogether and each $K$ has a start line and a result line. The result line is the start line of the next $K$ value. So the result line of the first step is also the first line of the second step.

**Note:** We do not need any induction based proof. The proof of the general step is sufficient as it was done here corresponding to the first part of @user5713492's answer.

Comment: @BLAZE: Good to see the answer is helpful and good review. :-) Typos corrected. Please, check again.

Comment: Hi, I made a few small changes to your answer for clarity. Please comment if you agree/disagree with it. Congratulations on your bounty, why no one else besides me upvoted your answer is a mystery to me! It should have like $5$ votes or more in my opinion. Thank you :-)

Comment: @BLAZE: Many thanks for accepting the answer and granting the bounty. I agree with your changes, everything is fine! :-) Since this answer addresses a very specific aspect, I suppose the interest of the users (and so the number of upvotes) is rather small. Regards,

Comment: In my studies of series solutions to ODE's I am now teaching myself Bessel's differential equation and it's solution(s). I was wondering if you would take a look at the [following question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794001/bessels-equation-textbook-queries)? Kindest regards :-)

Answer (score 2):

We are trying to evaluate
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell+m-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx$$
For $0\le n<m$. Let $$u=\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}$$
Then $$du=\frac{d^{\ell+1-m+n}}{dx^{\ell+1-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx$$
And $$dv=\frac{d^{\ell+m-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx$$
So $$v=\frac{d^{\ell+m-1-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-1-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}$$
Integrating by parts,
$$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1u\,dv&=\left.u\,v\right|_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1v\,du\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx\\
&=\left.\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m-1-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-1-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\right|_{-1}^1\\
&-\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell+m-1-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-1-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell-m+1+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+1+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx\\
&=-\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell+m-1-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-1-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell-m+1+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+1+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx\end{align}$$
Let's see... we were tasked with establishing that for any polynomial $p(x)$ and any $0\le n<k$ there is a polynomial $q(x)$ such that
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left((x-x_0)^kp(x)\right)=(x-x_0)^{k-n}q(x)$$
Well, it's true for $n=0$, and if true for some $0\le n<k-1$,
$$\begin{align}\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\left((x-x_0)^kp(x)\right)&=\frac d{dx}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left((x-x_0)^kp(x)\right)\\
&=\frac d{dx}\left((x-x_0)^{k-n}q(x)\right)\\
&=(k-n)(x-x_0)^{k-n-1}q(x)+(x-x_0)^{k-n}q^{\prime}(x)\\
&=(x-x_0)^{k-n-1}\left((k-n)q(x)+(x-x_0)q^{\prime}(x)\right)\\
&=(x-x_0)^{k-n-1}r(x)\end{align}$$
Where $r(x)$ is a polynomial. Having established the proposition for $n=0$ and having demonstrated its validity for $n+1$ given that it is true for $n<k-1$, it follows by mathematical induction for $0\le n<k$. From this we may conclude that
$$\left.\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m-1-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-1-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\right|_{-1}^1=0$$
For $n<m$ because $\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}$ still has at least one of its $\ell$ factors of $(x^2-1)$ left in it.

Using this result, we now are requested to show that for $0\le n\le m$,
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell-m}}{dx^{\ell-m}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m}}{dx^{\ell+m}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx\\=(-1)^n\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx$$
Clearly it's true for $n=0$, and way back up at the top, we showed that if it's true for $0\le n<m$, then
$$\begin{align}&\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell-m}}{dx^{\ell-m}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m}}{dx^{\ell+m}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx\\
&=(-1)^n\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx\\
&=(-1)^n\left\{-\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell+m-1-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-1-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell-m+1+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+1+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx\right\}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell+m-1-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-1-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell-m+1+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+1+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx\end{align}$$
So it's true for $n+1\le m$, thus the result follows by mathematical induction and in particular for $n=m$,
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell-m}}{dx^{\ell-m}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m}}{dx^{\ell+m}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx=(-1)^m\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell}}{dx^{\ell}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell}}{dx^{\ell}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx$$
Thus we can see that
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{d^{\ell+m}}{dx^{\ell+m}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell-m}}{dx^{\ell-m}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}dx=(-1)^m\int_{-1}^1\left(2^{\ell}\ell!P_{\ell}(x)\right)^2dx=\frac{2\cdot2^{2\ell}(\ell!)^2}{2\ell+1}$$
Where we have used the Rodrigues formula for the Legendre polynomials
$$P_{\ell}(x)=\frac1{2^{\ell}\ell!}\frac{d^{\ell}}{dx^{\ell}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer. There is one step in your calculation (marked red) for which I do not understand. Could you please elaborate and show intermediate steps for the part marked red? I know this is not always easy to do but I just need to know where the $(-1)^m$ factor comes from, as I don't know what you mean by "it takes at least $L$ derivatives to create a polynomial that is nonzero at either of these endpoints, and we know that , so $L−m$ derivatives is not enough. Then we had such success the first time, we repeated $m−1$ more times". Best Regards, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed one more thing; Could you please show how $\color{red}{(-1)^m\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{d^{L}}{dx^{L}}(x^2-1)^L\dfrac{d^{L}}{dx^{L}}(x^2-1)^Ldx}=(-1)^m\int_{-1}^1\left(2^LL!P_L(x)\right)^2dx$? Can't figure that part out either :( Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again, I don't follow your logic for the yellow highlighted part as it was my understanding that $\bbox[#AFA]{\left.\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\frac{d^{\ell+m-1-n}}{dx^{\ell+m-1-n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}\right|_{-1}^1=0}$ no matter what the derivatives are, since we just substitute the limits into the expression and it is equal to zero since $([-1]^2-1)^L=0,([1]^2-1)^L=0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: I painstakingly proved just above that part that $$\frac{d^{\ell-m+n}}{dx^{\ell-m+n}}(x^2-1)^{\ell}=(x^2-1)^{m-n}q(x)$$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. That is $0$ for $x\in\{-1,1\}$ if $n< m$.