# Show that $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(ml^2\dot\theta\right)+mgl\sin\theta=l\dfrac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}+2\dfrac{d\theta}{dl}+\dfrac{g}{v^2}\theta$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

`I have the following question from my textbook:`

> Suppose that a simple pendulum has the length $l$ of it's string increased at a steady rate (for example, a weight swaying as it is lowered by a crane). Find the equation of motion for small oscillations.
>
> For a simple pendulum; it's equation of motion is given by $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(ml^2\dot\theta\right)+mgl\sin\theta=0\tag{1}$$
>   Let the length $l$ of the string at time $t$ be $$l=l_0+vt\tag{2}$$ and change from $t$ to $l$ as the independent variable. For small oscillations, we may replace $\sin \theta$ by $\theta$.
>
> Hence show that equation $(1)$ becomes
>   $$l\dfrac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}+2\dfrac{d\theta}{dl}+\dfrac{g}{v^2}\theta=0\tag{3}$$
>   *Hint*: From equation $(2)$ $dl=v\,dt$, so $$\dfrac{d}{dt}=v\dfrac{d}{dl}$$

---

`My attempt:`

Using the hint, equation $(1)$ becomes $$v\dfrac{d}{dl}\left(ml^2\dot\theta\right)+mgl\theta=0$$
$$\implies v\dfrac{d}{dl}\left(l^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)+gl\theta=0$$
$$\implies v\left(2l\frac{d\theta}{dl}+l^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}\cdot v\right)+gl\theta=0\tag{a}$$
Where in $(\mathrm{a})$ I used the product rule along with the chain rule for the second term, namely $$\frac{d}{dl}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{d}{dl}\frac{d\theta}{dl}\frac{dl}{dt}=\frac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}\cdot v$$ 
Simplifying $(\mathrm{a})$ gives $$2v\frac{d\theta}{dl}+lv^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}+g\theta=0$$
$$\implies l\frac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}+2\frac{1}{v}\frac{d\theta}{dl}+\frac{g}{v^2}\theta=0$$ which is identical to $(3)$ with the exception of the $\dfrac{1}{v}$ factor in the second term.

I have already checked the [errata list](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~boas/Boas_MathematicalMethods_errata.pdf) for the book and there is no error. So this leads me to believe I am making a mistake somewhere.

Is there any chance someone could point out the error in my calculation?

Comment: $$\dfrac{d}{dl}\left(l^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)=2l\frac{d\theta}{d\color{red}{\bf t}}+l^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}\cdot v\ne2l\frac{d\theta}{dl}+l^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}\cdot v$$

Comment: @Did Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @Did I have [this bounty question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804280/verify-y-xaz-p-leftbxc-right-is-a-solution-to-y-left-frac1-2ax-ri) that no one is able to answer. I know that you given great answers/comments to my questions in the past so I was wondering if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$v\dfrac{d}{dl}\left(l^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)+gl\theta=0$$
>   $$\implies v\left(2l\frac{d\theta}{dl}+l^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dl^2}\cdot
>  v\right)+gl\theta=0\tag{a}$$

Here, you made the mistake:

> $$v\frac{d\theta}{dt}\dfrac{d}{dl}\left(l^2\right)=2vl\frac{d\theta}{dl}$$

The $dt$ in the term $\dfrac{d}{dl}$ changed to $dl$ for no reason.

Actually, it should be

$$v\frac{d\theta}{dt}\dfrac{d}{dl}\left(l^2\right)=2vl\frac{d\theta}{dt}=2vl\frac{d\theta}{dl}\cdot \frac{dl}{dt}=2v^2l\frac{d\theta}{dl}$$

Hope this helps.